# Laravel - Error - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'vegetable_stock_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: sql, laravel

im completely new to Laravel and i'm having an FK issue when creating a new vegetable on my website.

I have two tables , one called vegetables and another called vegetables_stock.
The two are linked with an FK in the Vegetables migration, called vegetable_stock_id.

here is my vegetable table.

```
    $table->id(); 
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('vegetable_stock_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('stock');
    $table->string('name', 50);
    $table->float('cost');
```

here is my vegetable_stock table

```
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('stock');
```

on my view I have a form for filling out for new vegetables, which should add the item to the vegetable table and update my vegetable_stock with the specified amount in the form.

The new vegetable cannot be successfully added to the table because on submit it's trying to retrieve a FK input and I get the error:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'vegetable_stock_id' doesn't have a default value...

I don't want to set a default value, I would like it so when the button is pressed an entry is made in the vegetable_Stock table and the form grabs the FK generated and then the stock on the Vegetable_Stock Table is populated with the input of the stock textbox within the form.

Could anyone advise any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: When you already have a stock column on vegetables table why do you need vegetable_stock table? What all values /data are you getting from the form when the request reaches the controller method? It would help if you can post code of your blade view containing the form and the controller method responsible for storing

Comment: You can make it nullable, if you dont want to insert `$table->unsignedBigInteger('vegetable_stock_id')->nullable();`

Answer (score 0):

update your migration or make new migration add this
`$table->unsignedBigInteger('vegetable_stock_id')->nullable();`

Comment: I said I don't want to make it nullable

Comment: then you can use intial value as zero , or if you make this column string then you can put a string into it or whatever you want